# How can I keep open my mat dialogue modal if Angular route getting change in Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, mat-dialog

I am implementing the multiple dialogue modal functionality to open multiple dialogue at a time and not closed until we closed manually.

Expected Behaviour: In this feature we allow user to open modal on
click of navigation bar and it is draggable and resizeable modal.
After open 1st modal user can open other modals by clicking on
navigation bar band 1st modal will remain same.

Getting Issue: I am facing issue while click on navigation bar to
open other modals it will change the routes and close the 1st
modal.

I am able to implement multiple modal at a time functionality for the same route and same page but not able to use it with route change.

What can I try?

Comment: Did you try the `closeOnNavigation` option (set to false obviously) ? I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but it might do the trick : https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig